# How to skip a Spring front controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, filter

I would like to create filter that must run before Spring front controller (MVC). In my filter, if some condition is true , i need to skip the front controller and run my own operation and return a page to viewer.

Comment: Filter is executed first and after that request goes to controller.

Comment: How to skip the controller?

Comment: Just don't call chain.doFilter(), but forward to a different servlet.